# Magento is not tracking most popular products

Tags: product

Not Getting most popular products .I have category in which most popular product will list down. What i did

Create a CMS Block

`{{block type="catalog/product_mostviewed" template="catalog/product/viewed.phtml"}}`

Then in **MANAGE CATEGORY** sections -> **DISPLAY SETTING**
[image: MOST POPULAR]

**viewed.phtml**

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class=" most_viewed">
<div class="mv_title"><?php echo $this->__('These Products Are Popular Right Now!') ?></div>
<?php $_collectionSize = 5;//count($_products->getItems()); echo $_collectionSize; ?>
<ul class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <li id="td_<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i%5==0 or $i==$_collectionSize){echo 'class="last"';} ?> >
        <div id="cont_<?php echo $i;?>">        
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
            <div class="a-center">                        
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability"><span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                    <li class="last"><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; $kol = $_collectionSize; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the block with type `catalog/product_mostviewed` does not exist in Magento. 
If you created the block make sure you did it right. Check you var/log folder for errors.

[Update]
If you really want to see if the action of viewing a product is registered look in the database in table `report_event`. Search for records with `event_type_id = 1`. If there are such records it means the event is tracked.
There is an other chance that you don't see any product because a refresh to the statistics is needed (Reports->Refresh statistics).

Comment: Check **Step 3** :
[link]http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-show-most-viewed-best-selling-products-in-magento-store/

Comment: The tutorial you suggested worked perfectly. this means you are doing something wrong. I updated the answer, maybe that helps.

Comment: Not working for me. i am following exact the same steps. also checked the **report_event**. its is tracking records.

Answer (score 0):

```
App/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mostviewed.php
```

added the following code:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addViewsCount();
        $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', microtime())
            ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', microtime());
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getProductCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
}
```

Your template should be like this:

```
<?php $_collection = $this->getProductCollection(); ?>

<!-- top pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>

<?php if($_collection->getSize()): ?>
    ...
    <?php foreach ($_collection as $_item): ?>
       ...
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif ?>

<!-- bottom pagination -->
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
```

Good luck for you!